# How to find all executable files? (AIX)

Tags: unix, shell, aix

example

```
-rwxr--r--    1 me     users             0 May 27 13:58 file_0
-rw-rwxrw-    1 me     users             0 May 27 13:58 file_1
-rw-rw-rwx    1 me     users             0 May 27 13:59 file_2
-rwxrwxrwx    1 me     users             0 May 27 14:02 file_3
```

I would need to list all 4 files in the current dir

- AIX
- non-gnu 'find', so "find . -executable" won't work

Comment: You want to do this from the command line or from a program?

Comment: webwesen, can you retitle this to be "How to find all executable files on AIX?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
find . -type f \( -perm -u=x -o -perm -g=x -o -perm -o=x \)
```

worked for me. any other solutions?

Answer (score 5):

```
find . -type f -perm +111
```

From `find(1)`:

> **-perm** [-|+]*mode*
>
> > The *mode* may be either symbolic (see `chmod(1)`) or an octal number. If the *mode* is symbolic, a starting value of zero is assumed and the *mode* sets or clears permissions without regard to the process’ file mode creation mask. If the *mode* is octal, only bits 07777 (`S_ISUID | S_ISGID | S_ISTXT | S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO`) of the file’s mode bits participate in the comparison. If the *mode* is preceded by a dash ("`-`"), this primary evaluates to true if at least all of the bits in the mode are set in the file’s mode bits. If the *mode* is preceded by a plus ("`+`"), this primary evaluates to true if any of the bits in the *mode* are set in the file’s mode bits. Otherwise, this primary evaluates to true if the bits in the *mode* exactly match the file’s mode bits. Note, the first character of a symbolic mode may not be a dash ("`-`").

Not specified in SUSv3, but portable across *BSD and Linux at least (I haven't tested others).

Comment: I tried that before posting - does not work on AIX - at least. nothing is returned. $ uname -a AIX xyz 3 5 00000000000 $ find . -type f -perm +111 $
||| sorry - formatting in comments is not supported apparently

Comment: that doesn't work on AIX 6 at least for me

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you like [Rube Goldberg devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine), you could use:

```
ls -l | grep '^[^d]\(..x\|.\{5\}x\|.\{8\}x\)' | awk '{ print $8 }'
```

Though this only lists the current directory.